# Dual pump system with a counter that changes between duty pump and standby every few times it runs

Tags: motor, control-system

I have a dual pump setup controlled by 3 floats. The lowest float stops the pump/s then the next one starts the pump selected for duty. The third float starts the other pump. The pumps can be changed manually to select which pump is on duty but I'd like to have it change every 4 times it runs. I'm just at a bit of a loss at trying to find the right style of relay/counter to make this possible. I have thought about using a timer to change them but can't see how it would ensure even running of both pumps as the duty pump.

Comment: why not use a better pump and 1 float switch with large hysteresis or low and high switch. If requirement is valid, make a logic table or state diagram or timing diagram .

Comment: There is almost certainly an analog way to do this, but if you're asking how it should be done, I would suggest a microcontroller, depending on the voltages and powers you're dealing with. Can you give more info about the system itself?

Comment: It strikes me that you should have an automatic changeover in case of failure, otherwise your wear leveling system may actually decrease the reliability (if **either** pump fails then it will never switch off so you have a system failure).

Comment: Lead lag alternation of sequential pump systems is a very common requirement for sewage lift station pumps. You can probably find a ready-made product or detailed descriptions of control schemes that you can use.

Answer (score 1):

A micro-PLC (programmable logic controller) is ideal for this. They are very flexible, come in a variety of voltages (24 V DC, 110/230 V AC), relay or transistor outputs, etc., are industrially hardened and user programmable. Many allow writing of the program from a keypad / LCD on the unit or via PC software.

[image]

*Figure 1. A typical DIN-rail mount micro-PLC.*

Your program can be written in Ladder Logic - a diagramatic representation of an electrical circuit. In your case it might look like this.

```
' Turn on duty pump when FloatMid turns on. 
' Hold on until FloatLow turns off.
   FloatMid                                     DutyPump
----| |-------------------+-----------------------( )----
                          |
   DutyPump     FloatLow  |
----| |-----------| |-----+

' Turn on standby pump when FloatHi turns on. 
' Hold on until FloatLow turns off.
   FloatHi                                      StandbyPump
----| |-------------------------------------------( )----
                          |
   StandbyPump  FloatLow  |
--- | |-----------| |-----+

' Counter 0 counts first four cycles. Couter 1 the next four.
   DutyPump                                        K4
----| |------+-----------------------------------[CNT 0]---
             |
             |   CNT 0                             K4
             +----| |----------------------------[CNT 1]---

' After eight cycles reset both counters to zero.
   CNT 1                                         CNT 0
----| |--------------------------------------+---[RST}-----
                                             |
                                             |   CNT 1
                                             +---[RST]-----

' Pump 1 should run for the first four cycles or in standby
' for the next four.
   DutyPump      CNT 0                           PUMP 1
----| |-----------|/|-----+----------------------( )-------
                          |
   StandbyPump    CNT0    |
--- | |-----------| |-----+

' Pump 2 should run for the second four cycles or in standby
' for the first four.
   DutyPump       CNT 0                          PUMP 2
----| |-----------| |-----+----------------------( )-------
                          |
   StandbyPump    CNT0    |
--- | |-----------|/|-----+

' Give an alarm if FloatHi turns on. Latch until ACKN button
' is pressed.
   FloatHi     ACKN                              Fault
----| |----+----|/|------------------------------( )-------
           |
   Fault   |
----| |----+
```

Notes:

```
--| |--          Contact. Power flow when TRUE.
--|/|--          Contact. Power flow when FALSE.
--( )--          Coil. Can be an internal "flag" or a physical output.
--[RST]--        Reset coil.
--[CNT x]--      Counter. Starts at zero and increments on each positive-
                 -going edge of the input up to the preset value. When the
                 preset value is reached the counter turns on.
```

Examine the options carefully before you buy and try the demo software. Once you get started on this you will find many more applications so you should choose a brand and device that will meet your future needs.

Comment: +1 I suppose these small DIN rail devices could be called gateway PLCs :-)  Certainly a very good solution to the level of robustness required if an off the shelf solution is unavailable.

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually, any binary counter with 3 bits or more, in any logic family, hooked up with the clock input driven by the lower float, and the third output going to a pump select relay, will do the job.

Suitable binary counters would be x161, x393, x4020, 2x x74 ... The list is not endless, but there are many other types that could be used.

You need to take care with implementation though. You don't say what voltage the pump runs from, or what levels are present on the float switches, but they obviously have to be translated and isolated, safely, to and from logic levels. The float switch output has to be debounced, a mechanical switch tends to make many edges when it operates, not noticeable if switching a pump, but capable of clocking logic many times. And then of course there's the interface to the pump select relay. Ideally, you'd use a little more logic to power the relay only when a pump is required to run, rather than have a changeover relay powered all the time.

The obvious way to do it is to use a microcontroller. This would be able to debounce the input, have a push-to-test input for the motors, only run them at certain times, sound an alarm if both had been running for more than x time, sound an alarm if the primary pump fails to come on (is the redundancy of the dual-pump arrangement a safety feature?), change the switch-over from 4 times to 5 times, in fact any extra feature you can think of and describe, with no or little extra hardware. This latter point is perhaps the most powerful reason for avoiding a microcontroller like the plague, and sticking with 'single function' logic!

A much more fun way would be a motor, gearbox and cams, whereby the motor runs to the next position when a pump goes on, and then runs a bit more when it goes off, completing one eighth of a shaft revolution every pump operation. A cam and switch on the shaft does the rest. Something strictly for the mechanical makers!

Obviously these methods described above are homebrew. Your comment of *I'm just at a bit off a loss at trying to find the right style of relay/counter to make this possible* sounds like you might be looking for a ready-packaged solution, like the types of plug-in timer that can be bought. I think it's unlikely you'll find a ready made solution, given that this is an unusual function to be performed.

If you do want a method for doing this such that your fire insurance guy or your electrician won't have a fit, then it's expensive, but a small industrial control system can be put together to do this. They tend to have DIN-rail clippable input, output and PLC modules, they are safe and mains rated, look (are) professional, and can be programmed to do what function you like.

Comment: "I think it's unlikely you'll find a ready made solution, given that this is an unusual function to be performed." This is a common requirement for sewage lift station pumps.